# Logo manufacturer appears twice when booting

Tags: grub2

I got strange thing when booting with my laptop Acer Helios 300 2019:

1. I have just installed new Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on a new SSD. During the process installing on the SSD, I didn't format the existing HDD which already had Ubuntu.
2. After having new Ubuntu on the SSD, when booting, GRUB appears for me to choose which Ubuntu to boot (from SSD or HDD).
3. I choose to boot from the SSD.
4. When being in the Ubuntu of SSD, I format the HDD by GParted.
5. I update the GRUB to make sure it deletes the obsolete information.

   `sudo update-grub`
6. After this action, GRUB doesn't appear anymore when booting but strange thing happens here: the logo Predator (from laptop manufacturer) appears twice when booting. In the between of the two times is exactly 10 seconds purple screen similar to GRUB but the menu GRUB doesn't actually appear.

Link of the problem recording here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yLrrstUyKo&lc=z22qvxq4yzudz3ewh04t1aokgk1xmtl5lqyo3rlmpci1rk0h00410

I suspect that I did something wrong with the GRUB. Can anyone help? (I'm new to Ubuntu for a few days). Thank you.

Updates:
I modify my Grub file as follow:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

The purple screen still appears. And following is output of `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode



menuentry "Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic root=UUID=26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603 ro  quiet splash pci=nomsi $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic
}
submenu "Advanced options for Ubuntu"{
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-40-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-40-generic-advanced-26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-40-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic root=UUID=26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603 ro  quiet splash pci=nomsi $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-40-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-40-generic-recovery-26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-40-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic root=UUID=26b553f8-52e8-4e28-953e-d0b62bba9603 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: I thought when I format the HDD and update the GRUB then nothing of the HDD should remain? Anyway, I correct the grub file:  

'GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0'
'GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true'

and add:
'GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER= true'
 
The time of the interrupting purple screen reduces from 10s to 3s but it's still there.

Situation at the moment:
1. Logo Predator (1s) 
2. **Purple screen (a few to 10s)** 
3. Logo Predator (3s)
4. Ubuntu starting screen (1s)

Comment: Hey @Gryu, you're right. When I press ESC on the purple screen, the GRUB menu appears. Do you know how to get rid of it?  I have modified the Grub file as this website http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/ubuntu-1404-hide-grub-menu/ but it just helps reduce the time of purple screen from 10s to about 5s.

Comment: Show also what the `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg` shows. Past its output in your question.

Comment: i had a win 10 desktop which always showed a hp-logo of the manufacturer just like your laptop´s predato, before starting the actual boot.. but. after messing around to finally get xubuntu installed on the thing (lots of things done, including deleting uefi keys) that logo is no more. it only shows Xubuntu during boot.

Comment: I have updated my questions.
@BasLamerichs I would like to stick with Ubuntu because I'm totally new to Linux so I hope Ubuntu has greater community that have more already answered questions.

Updates: I have formatted all SSD and HDD and installed again totally new Ubuntu on SSD but the problem is not yet fixed.